# How can I set DTSTART property of iCalendar to my timezone when converting excel to iCal in python?

Tags: python, excel, icalendar

I've been trying to set the `DTSTART` property of iCal to `DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin` in my python script which is converting events in an excel sheet to iCal events:

```
out_cal = Calendar()
for i, row in df_entries.iterrows():
    ev = Event()
    ev.name = row['name']
    ev.description = row['description']
    ev.begin = row['begin']
    ev.end = row['end']
    ev.location = row['location']
out_cal.events.add(ev)
```

By default I will get the .ics output:

test.ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:ics.py - http://git.io/lLljaA
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION: (private)
DTEND:20220203T134500Z
LOCATION: (private)
DTSTART:20220203T114500Z
SUMMARY: (private)
UID: (private)
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

By default the UTC time is set with `DTSTART:20211019T081500Z`. I need to change the VTIMEZONE and set DTSTART;TZID="Europe/Berlin". How do I do that in python??

Comment: Could you please provide your code or at least a part of it ? And maybe elaborate with it a little bit.

Comment: edited it a bit.

Comment: Is this [iCalendar](https://pypi.org/project/icalendar/) library the one that you are using ? Also could you please provide one of the rows from excel ? Feel free to not include/censor any private data

Comment: Yes, I'm importing: 
`import os import json import datetime import pandas as pd from ics import Calendar, Event`
`
 I'm also changing the time: 
`def transform_time(in_date, in_time): # output format '2014-01-01 00:00:00' # date out_date = '-'.join(reversed(in_date.split('.'))) # time out_time = in_time + ':00' print(out_time)' return out_date + ' ' + out_time`

 With excel everything is working. What exactly do you mean by sending the rows? For what reason? Thanks!!